# Why is pytesseract not identifying this image?

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to identify single digits in python with tesseract.

My code is this:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageOps
import pytesseract
import cv2

def predict(imageArray):
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
    newImageArray = Image.open(imageArray)
    number = pytesseract.image_to_string(newImageArray, lang='eng', config='--psm 10 --oem 1 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')

    return number
```

It has no problem saying this is an `8`

[image: Image1]

but it does not recognise this as a `4`

[image: Image2]

My images are just digits `0-9`.

This is just one such example there are other instances where it struggles to identify "obvious/clear" digits.

Currently the only thing I am doing to my starting image,`image` is converting the colour. Using the following:

`cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

Is there a way I can improve the accuracy. All of my images are clear computer typed images so I feel the accuracy should be a lot higher than it is.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide any information about your tesseract version and language model you used.
Best model identify '4' in your image without any preprocessing.

Comment: which is the best model? I am using python with pytesseract and tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v5.0.0-alpha.20200223.

Comment: Read tesseract docs: https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ We will not do it instead of you.